# how can a jenkins build/clone a remote git repo which is mounted into it's docker container?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, synology

I have a private Synology NAS Cloud which supports Docker containers.
Now i plan a private build and deploy pipeline or something like this.

My first steps which are done:

1. install Git Server on the Synology
2. init some Repos
3. clone them on my MacBook
4. communicate over ssh (commit, push, pull)

--> all works fine.

Now i have started a Docker container on the NAS with a Jenkins image. i want the Jenkins to poll my remote repository on the NAS (same repository which i cloned on my MacBook).
I also mounted the "/git" folder with all the remote repositories into the Jenkins Docker container.

So I want to add the repository URL to a Jenkins job: 
`file:///git/firstRepo`
 ---> but that doesn't work :(

```
    ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from file:///git/firstRepo
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:817)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1084)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1115)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at
       hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.    java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress file:///git/firstRepo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: '/git/firstRepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:352)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:815)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tested to clone the repo via docker shell into the Jenkins workspace with 
`git clone file:///git/firstRepo`
-> that works. But there I am logged in with "root".


**so my question is:**
How can Jenkins access the git folder? Is it a problem with the access rights? Obviously the Jenkins is not the "root". Do i have to "chown" the git folder to my Jenkins user (which i think is "admin")?



**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: Please limit your question to one specific question, not two.

Comment: ok i can do that - thanks

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what does that mean? Is there an error? What are in the Jenkins container logs when it tries to clone this? Can you provide the `docker inspect` output of the container so we can verify the user and other runtime parameters?

Comment: it is the "standard error" from git, when it isn't a repository, or when u don't have the access rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the path: usually, those repos (used for pushing) are bare repos, meaning their path should be a folder with a .git extension.

```
.../git/firstRepo.git
```

Second, try a simple Jenkins Job (without any SCM setting) with a simple build step

```
id -a
ls -alrth /git
ls -alrth /git/firstRepo
ls -alrth /git/firstRepo.git
```

That will show you the rights associated with those paths, and tells you if Jenkins (executed as the user shown in `id -a`) has the right or not to access that path.

Comment: hmm yes obviously it is a bare repo. but i tried it also with the ".git" extension and it didn't work. but the second job tells me the he can't open the folder because permission denied. So i think i have to change the rights?

Comment: I mean, the naming convention for a bare repo root folder is xxx.git. maybe not in your case though.

Comment: Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/rights
[rights] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3950076998126083093.sh
+ id -a
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)
+ ls -alrth /git
ls: cannot open directory '/git': Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: OK, si the way/git is mounted prevent that use to access it.

Comment: yes you are right. but locally i clone it also without this extension and it works. and also as i wrote on top, i cloned it in the docker container from /git/firstRepo to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ and it also works. only the jenkins gui can't clone it.

Comment: ok how can i change the rights correctly? i did a "chown jenkins /git" and a "chmod 644 /git/" - now your job gets one step further but it says "ls: cannot access '/git/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/git/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/git/@eaDir': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/git/#recycle': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/git/firstRepo': Permission denied" -- so he hasn't rights for the subfolders. do i have to change all subfolders now?

Comment: @m1well You can try and chow your volume when mounting it: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259#issuecomment-313866406

Comment: @m1well Other ideas, more related to Jenkins: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/263#issuecomment-217912585